# Cant connect to socket.io on nodejs applcation deployed in cpanel

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io, cpanel

I am contructing a web applicaction using react, nodejs and socke.io. I tested the socket connection in my localhost and i am uploading the server to a website. The server is running in a folder like this https://testavirtual.com/be.

On the server I am using sokcet.io like this:

```
var app = express();
var server = http.Server(app);
var io = socketIO(server);
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log("Socket connected", socket.id);
})
//For production i am not establishing the port as I am publishing the site on a cpanel folder.
server.listen();
```

In my React application y am trying to connect to the server like this:

```
const endpoint = "https://testavirtual.com/be";
const socket = socketIOClient(endpoint);
```

A CORS error like this:

Solicitud desde otro origen bloqueada: la política de mismo origen impide leer el recurso remoto en https://testavirtual.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N6j26SU (razón: falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin').

Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: Before `io.on` add `io.origins('*:*')` I believe this should fix your problem

Comment: Hello, i tried but it didn't work, I think it has to do with the way the proyecto is deployed as the nodejs app is in a folder inside the website.

Comment: hey! have you completed this? I am facing issue on connecting socket.io in cpanel.